# Saving image to gallery not working since upgrade to android 7

Tags: android, image, android-gallery, android-7.0-nougat

I am developing some Android app and using the regular camera (not a custom one). The app has all the necessary permissions (camera, write and read external). Until yesterday everything worked fine: after shot, the image saved in device gallery and could be displayed in `ImageView`. I upgraded to Android 7.0 and now the camera doesn't save the image anymore and the activity results return `null` (`data.getData()`).

Does anyone know what's changed in Android 7.0?

Comment: use this in your class `cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, picUri);`

Comment: Well show your code i would say.

Comment: `and now the camera doesn't save the image anymore `. Cameras do not save images. Only a Camera app can do so. Are you using one? Can you still take pictures the normal way with the camera app on your device?

Comment: `the image saved in device gallery `. No. Images are saved in the device storage. One cannot save images to the gallery as the Gallery app is no storage place but just an app that shows pictures which are on the device.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SaveImageAsync extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {


        try {


            InputStream in;
            BufferedInputStream buf;
            int position = params[0];

            if (URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(use image here)) {
                in = new URL(use image here
                ).openStream();


                buf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
                Bitmap _bitmapPreScale = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
                int oldWidth = _bitmapPreScale.getWidth();
                int oldHeight = _bitmapPreScale.getHeight();
                int newWidth = 2592;
                int newHeight = 1936;

                float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / oldWidth;
                float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / oldHeight;

                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

                matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
                Bitmap _bitmapScaled = Bitmap.createBitmap(_bitmapPreScale, 0, 0, oldWidth, oldHeight, matrix, true);


                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                _bitmapScaled.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);

                File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM),"wave");
                directory.mkdirs();
                directory.mkdir();


                File f = new File(directory, "writeurnamefolder_Gallery" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");


                f.createNewFile();

                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());

                fo.close();
            } else if (URLUtil.isFileUrl(use here original image)) {
                MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(get your image here.getPath(), "writeurnamefolder_Gallery" + System.currentTimeMillis(), "Gallery Image :");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: and you have to give these permission i hope this will help you.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
  MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS

Comment: What a bunch of not to the point code. Nobody asked for such code. What made you think so?

Answer (score 0):

**file://** is not allowed to attach with Intent anymore or it will throw FileUriExposedException which may cause your app crash immediately called.